# How to use enum in Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc, dropwizard

Hi I am creating an Api named as

```
getData(Request req)
```

Request class is like

```
@Data
public class Request(){

@NotNull
public int mobileNumber;

@NotNull
public int currentLocation;
}
```

I want to restrict client who is using my api to pass current Location from the Enum given below. How can I acheive this with anotation. I am working in **DropWizard framework**.

```
public enum Location {
    Us, Canada, India
}
```

Comment: Why not deserialize in Location enum type field ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the type of `currentLocation` to `Location`? E.g:

```java
@Data
public class Request() {

    @NotNull
    public int mobileNumber;

    @NotNull
    public Location currentLocation;
}
```

Then when a user sends a request with a body like

```json
{
    mobileNumber: 12234,
    currentLocation: "Canada"
{
```

Dropwizard will map the string into a enum for you. If the user tries to send a value that isn't inside the enum, Dropwizard will give them a suitable 400 response.

You may also want to consider having the type of `mobileNumber` a string, some phone numbers start with a leading zero, which will be removed in the mapping to int.